# Empty configs from local repository Spring Cloud

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-cloud

Пытаюсь развернуть Spring Cloud Server в docker, но получаю пустую конфигурацию. Если запускать сбилженный jar, то при переходе на localhost:7999/project/test конфигурация отображается. Конфигурация хранится локально в основной папке докера, использую native профиль, в качестве пути использую searchLocations: classpath:/configs

Что можно сделать, чтобы была видна папке с конфигами ?
Структура такая:

Docker:

1. -configs
2. -dist (тут лежит jar файл с cloud server)

Comment: `в основной папке докера` - это какая папка имеется ввиду? Нет такого понятия "основная папка докера". Вы можете собирать образ миллионом разных способов. Покажите Dockerfile и команду, которой вы запускаете контейнер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прокинул из базовой папки (где все файлы), папку с конфигами через docker-compose, клауд сервер увидел мои конфиги